# Tags are not positioned centrally when asking a question

Tags: bug, design

Here's a screenshot of me writing this question:

[image]

The tags aren't properly centered in the box. Chrome, OSX.

Comment: This is also somewhat true on Chrome, Win7. I'm not sure it's really a bug _per se_ — who says the text _needs_ to be centred? They have the padding they would were the `(x)` not there. But I admit it looks a bit odd.